# Summing of neutrino spins in Muon decay

Tags: homework-and-exercises, feynman-diagrams, neutrinos, spinors, matrix-elements

This might be a silly question, but I am just a beginner so please bear with me.

When we average the matrix element over spins, do we also have to sum over neutrino spins since neutrinos are only Left-handed? neutrino spin summing works the same way as other fermions or differently?
This example from Griffith looks like there is no difference except $m_\nu=0$

[image: Inverse muon decay from griffiths]

Comment: The sum you are talking about doesn't sum over the right handed partners of the electrons either even, if they exist, since the weak force only acts on the left handed particles of the SM. This is something you learn later on in the text when you get to the symmetries and group theory.

Comment: Oh okay, so this sum is only over spins, which are +1/2 and -1/2 for all fermions, regardless of neutrinos or electrons. and not over LH and RH states. Am I correct?

Comment: Indeed that is true, unfortunately I usually look on from mobile, if someone comes along and answers the question for real you might get a better fleshed out answer.